# What is the unit normal vector of the curve $y + x^2 = 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

> What is the unit normal vector of the curve $y + x^2 = 1$, $-1 \leq x \leq 1$?

I need this to calculate the flux integral of a vector field over that curve.

Comment: If you put dollar signs $ around your math it will format more nicely.

Comment: I have no idea where to even begin, given that this is a curve and not a plane with a given point where the unit normal vector would be obvious. I am not allowed to use the Divergence Theorem to compute the flux integral either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve is given by $F(x,y)=x^2+y-1=0$. A normal vector is $\operatorname{grad}{F}=(F_x,F_y)=(2x,1)$. We now normalize to get

$$n=\left(\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

A parametric equation for the curve is $$\mathbf{r}(t)=t\mathbf{i}+(1-t^2)\mathbf{j}\qquad t\in[-1,1]$$
We can find the unit tangent vector as $$\mathbf{T}(t)=\frac{\mathbf{r}'(t)}{\left|\mathbf{r}'(t)\right|}$$
After that, the unit normal vector can be find as
$$\mathbf{N}(t)=\frac{\mathbf{T}'(t)}{\left|\mathbf{T}'(t)\right|}$$

Answer (score 0):

this is another way used when you want to find the unit normal vector in plane
$$y=1-x^2$$
$$y'=-2x$$
$$v=2xi+j$$
$$|v|=\sqrt{(2x)^2+1^2}=\sqrt{4x^2+1}$$
$$n=\frac{v}{|v|}=\frac{2xi}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}+\frac{j}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}$$